# Can not get clientWidth using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get windowsize of the browser and according to this condition I want to render something in the component.
When I try to get clientWidth using useEffect, I get the value. However, I can not assign it the variable which I defined it in useState.

This is my code. and sometimes I'm getting the following error which I don't understand because I don't assign anything to constant variable. I try to assign variable of useState.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 400) {
      console.log(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
      setIsMobile = true;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {(() => {
        console.log(isMobile);
        if (isMobile === true) {
          return <div>This is Mobile</div>;
        } else {
          return <div>This is normal</div>;
        }
      })()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the written version in stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-i9ewp6?file=src/App.js

Comment: You want `setIsMobile(true)`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate... _"Returns a stateful value, and **a function to update it**."_

Comment: I think you mean to do `setIsMobile(true)`

Comment: Would `useLayoutEffect` help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to the `setIsMobile` state updater function, which is declared const, so you can't reassign a value to it anyway. You need to call the function with the value you want to update state to.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 400) {
    console.log(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    setIsMobile(true);
  }
}, []);
```

or more succinctly

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsMobile(document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 400);
}, []);
```

Since `isMobile` is a boolean value, it's considered anti-pattern to compare it against `true`|`false`, just use its "boolean-ness" directly.

```
return (
  <div>
    {isMobile ? (
      <div>This is Mobile</div>
    ) : (
      <div>This is normal</div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Also, if you want to log values do it in an `useEffect` hook as an intentional side-effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(isMobile);
}, [isMobile]);
```

Comment: I'd also throw in a _resize_ event listener

Comment: @Phil True, I had thought about that but since it seems OP is more or less trying to detect if running on mobile or not I don't they they are assuming window resizing.

Comment: I was more thinking for portrait / landscape orientation. There's probably a _right way_ to do that though (been years since I worked on mobile)

Comment: @Phil Ah, true, many use cases, and I'm making no assumptions about any of them. 